# Convert MBR/BIOS to GPT/UEFI (infodump)

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, ssd, gpt, mbr

I wanted to upgrade my 1.5TB HDD to a 4TB SSD, none of the internet resources I found correctly matched my situation from beginning to end, and I ended up spending about 20 hours getting it to work, so I'm compiling my findings here for future travelers.

Answer (score 0):

Base details: I have an old Dell Inspiron 5720 running Ubuntu 20.04.6.  I started with a 1.5TB HDD and bought a 4TB SSD.  I discovered that MBR, the partition table my old drive used, did not support partitions larger than ~2TB, so I was going to have to switch to GPT.  Apparently this almost inevitably entails switching your boot system from BIOS to UEFI, as well, which was really the primary source of problems.  (There's evidence there was a broken UEFI installation already present, as well, which may have complicated things.)

I copied Kali Linux onto a USB stick to help with the proceedings.  You can skip down to where I start listing steps, if you want the tl;dr.  I'm leaving the rest, and the lines in parentheses, in case the details help somebody figure out what's wrong with theirs.

The following is the first thing I tried, which **DID NOT WORK**.
It seemed like it would be safer to mess with a partition while it was not in use, so I booted the usb.  I plugged the SSD in with an adapter.  I opened gparted, and if I remember correctly, on the SSD I created a GPT partition table.  I then (in gparted) selected the HDD, copied the first partition, selected the SSD, pasted, and likewise for the second partition.  Reading UEFI guides, I MAY have created a third partition at the end for the UEFI partition, or I may have added that later when my first attempts failed.  I then waited for the copy to finish (like 4 hours), turned off the computer, and swapped hard drives, and tried to boot.  No dice.  I think the error was "No operation system", or something equally nearly-right.  Long story short, I tried a whole bunch of things for many hours, and none of them worked.  I then switched to plan B.

Plan B, which eventually DID work.
Most of the guides expected you to be booted into the system you wanted to convert, so first I swapped drives again and booted the usb and copied my hdd directly onto the ssd with `dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M of=/dev/sdc`, checking I had the right device.  (I nearly copied it the wrong way.)  The next morning, I swapped hard drives and booted successfully.  (The HDD was no longer used at any point past here.)  Next I (installed?) ran `gdisk /dev/sda`.  It said that there was a working MBR table, but also a corrupt GPT table.  I think it asked me which to proceed with, so I selected (1)MBR; and I don't THINK it made me select anything else before putting me into the main menu, so after poking around the options, did `w` for write.  Rebooted.  Got a blinking cursor on a black screen.  Eliding a lot of testing and false starts, but restating the first steps so the list is complete:

(Suggestion: check that your bios supports UEFI and otherwise update it; doing that earlier might have fixed some of my problems.)

**Be careful about copying, some of these commands use my specific drive numbers**

Boot from usb
Copy hdd onto ssd, e.g. `dd if=/dev/HDD bs=1M of=/dev/SSD` (get it right!!)
Turn off computer
Swap drives, put HDD somewhere safe in case you mess up and need to start over
Reboot into ssd
`gdisk /dev/sda`
(If it asks you to pick between a working MBR and a broken GPT, pick MBR)
`w` for "write"
Reboot into usb
(though it MIGHT work and not wreck your data to continue on to the following from your main os, and without the mounting and chroot stuff.  Might still need to mount the efi partition.)
Connect to the internet

```bash
sudo bash
apt update
apt install zfsutils-linux
modprobe zfs
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt  # sda5 was my main installation partition
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi   # sda1 I think was the partition originally intended to be the efi partition
modprobe efivarfs
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /run /mnt/run
chroot /mnt bash
apt install grub-efi
update-grub
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda
update-grub   # not sure whether it's supposed to go before or after install
```

(Hopefully I haven't missed any steps etc.)

I eventually realized my bios, Phoenix SecureCore Tiano version A03, was too old to support UEFI.  So I:
Downloaded the newest firmware from https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=khvck
Downloaded the FreeDOS FullUSB image from https://www.freedos.org/download/
`dd`'d the img file onto a usb
Replugged the usb
Mounted the usb's partition
Copied the bios EXE onto it
`sync` and shut down
Booted that USB (must be writable or the exe fails to extract)
Ran the exe file, which installed the new bios, version A17
Confirmed the bios now COULD work with UEFI, saw new options in the menus etc.
(Boot still failed, though I forget exactly how)
(I then used the boot menu to select the hard drive - Ubuntu *started* to boot, but showed "watchdog: BUG: soft lockup", and after a few minutes I restarted)
Selected hard drive from boot menu
Got a grub screen, and selected a maintenance mode shell

```bash
modprobe zfs
update-grub
grub-install
update-grub
reboot
```

(Bios now showed "ubuntu" in the uefi boot list, which worked, but the bios wouldn't automatically boot into it)
Selected hard drive in boot list, successful boot

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt install boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Ran suggested fixes, noting the sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi path it gave in the success dialog
(Reboot failed)
(I turned off Legacy Boot ROM option in the bios, and it DID boot correctly, but took away my other boot options, so I turned it back on.)
In bios, I selected "add boot", gave the boot option a name, left selected the only target present (some long string that I think referred to my hard drive or partitions or something), and the third box let me navigate to "EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi", and created the boot option.
Made sure that option was the first of the UEFI boot options.  (It had all the legacy options above the uefi ones, and wouldn't let me change that.)
It finally booted unaided
I used gparted from my os to resize my main partition
Successfully rebooted

I don't know how much of that is necessary, and how much could have been avoided by e.g. updating the bios first, and maybe skipping some of the boot-into-usb steps, but this is what ended up working, cobbled together from dozens of different SO posts and reddit posts and forum threads.

Comment: Almost always better to do new clean install to a new drive and restore your data from your backup. Good test that backup has everything you need as you still have old drive. You at minimum need /home, other data  & list of installed apps. You may want some settings in /etc, but best to to just reinstall it. New version may not be same. You cannot copy a MBR partition to a gpt drive, but copy data using rsync works.  Gpt partitions are totally different than MBR partitions.